# declaring two sections in tableView but only one appears

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm following along with a Lynda.com `iOS` tutorial on table views. The demo we're making is supposed to create a table view with two sections. The data for the two sections is imported from `plist` files in the `viewDidLoad` method of the controller (which is the delegate), and, as you can also see below, I declare that there should be two sections and give each section a header.

However, when I run it in the simulator only the first section (with the title 'iOS course' ) is appearing on screen (and I can't scroll down). The section for `web_courses` isn't appear.  From the code below, can you explain why the section for `web_courses` isn't appearing.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;

}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0){
        return @"iOS courses";
    }else {
        return @"web courses";

    }

}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0){
        return courseDetails.count;
    }else {
         return webCourseDetails.count;

    }

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"courses" withExtension:@"plist"];
    courseDetails = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url];

    justCourseNames = courseDetails.allKeys;

    NSURL *urlWeb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"courses_web" withExtension:@"plist"];
    webCourseDetails = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:urlWeb];
    webCourseNames = webCourseDetails.allKeys;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `webCourseDetails.count` returns `0` in `numberOfRowsInSection` method. That's why it is not appearing.

It can be that the `webCourseDetails` dictionary is `nil`. Set a breakpoint in `numberOfRowsInSection` to verify that. This would mean that the problem is in:

```
NSURL *urlWeb = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"courses_web" 
                                        withExtension:@"plist"];

webCourseDetails = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:urlWeb];
```

And the dictionary is not initialized e.g. because the plist file is not there.

Comment: I set a breakpoint as you suggested and the local variable `webCourseDetails` in that function `numberOfRowsInSection` says there are 11 key/value pairs.

Comment: At the bottom of the simulator, it's showing the top half of a row and the view's not letting me scroll down to see what it is, so maybe the other section is there but for some reason I just can't scroll to it.

Comment: actually the same thing's happening in the code supplied by the tutorial (when I run it on my machine) even though it works in the video.